# Who else knew that Lord Voldemort was Tom Marvolo Riddle?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

We know that **some** people were aware of the fact that Lord Voldemort was Tom Marvolo Riddle prior to his return in **Goblet of Fire**; at the very least his close soon-to-be-Death-Eater "friends" and Albus Dumbledore:

> “Very few people know that Lord Voldemort was once called Tom Riddle. I taught him myself, fifty years ago, at Hogwarts..."
>
> ... underwent so many dangerous, magical transformations, that when he resurfaced as Lord Voldemort, he was barely recognizable. **Hardly anyone connected Lord Voldemort with the clever, handsome boy who was once Head Boy here.**” (Professor Dumbledore to Weasleys, *Chamber of Secrets*, CHAPTER EIGHTEEN, Dobby’s Reward)

and

> “Voldemort,” said Riddle softly, “is my past, present, and future, Harry Potter…”
>
> He pulled Harry’s wand from his pocket and began to trace it through the air, writing three shimmering words:
>
> TOM MARVOLO RIDDLE
>
> Then he waved the wand once, and the letters of his name rearranged themselves:
>
> I AM LORD VOLDEMORT
>
> “You see?” he whispered. “**It was a name I was already using at Hogwarts, to my most intimate friends only, of course.** ...  (Tom's Diary manifestation in the *Chamber of Secrets*).

**QUESTION**:

**Who - based on canon (books/interviews/pottermore) - knew about the fact that Lord Voldemort was Tom Marvolo Riddle *prior to Ginny being taken to the Chamber of Secrets*?**

Obviously, Albus Dumbledore and Tom himself. Who else?

Comment: You'd think that when Riddle stopped showing up at class reunions when Voldemort popped up out of nowhere someone might put things together.

Comment: Rather than dupe, I'd suggest we merge these two; namely, the other one into this one.

Comment: @Mooz is that even possible for such old questions?

Comment: @SQB I'm pretty sure mods can merge anything.

Comment: I agree with @Möoz, this isn't a duplicate. This is related, but the answers here give many more examples and much more information.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Lestange and Avery are known to be members of Tom Riddle's gang while at Hogwarts.

> "Lestrange, I want that essay on my desk by tomorrow or it's detention. Same goes for you, Avery." - Slughorn's memory from the Slugclub and Tom Riddle's gang.

Slughorn himself is likely to know. Particularly with Tom Riddle asking him about horcruxes, and Dumbledore later coming around to collect memories about Tom Riddle.

Helena Ravenclaw (ghost) knew the identity of Tom Riddle as the person to whom she gave the location of the diadem, and who subsequently became Lord Voldemort.

Comment: I think Burke of Borgin and Burke's had a fair idea as well.

Answer (score 24):

Mr. Ollivander knew.

> Mr Ollivander touched the lightning scar on Harry's forehead with a long, white finger.
>
> "I'm sorry to say I sold the wand that did it," he said softly. "Thirteen and a half inches. Yew. Powerful wand, very powerful, and in the wrong hands ... Well, if I’d known what that wand was going out into the world to do ..."
>
> He shook his head and then, to Harry's relief, spotted Hagrid.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, by way of [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/a-curious-wand)</sub>

He obviously knew who Voldemort was, because he knew that Voldemort gave the scar, and he knew Voldemort's wand, and he knew that he sold that wand to Tom Riddle.

Comment: Good catch. People forget Ollivander for some reason :) Now the actual question - _how_ did he know Tom was now Voldemort?

Comment: Hello, Rajat Ligade, and welcome to [fantasy.se] That's a good first answer! May I interest you in taking the [tour]?

Comment: @Gallifreyan that would be interesting to know, but the question only asks _who_, not _how_.

Comment: @SQB I would disagree. If Ollivander don't have an exclusive source of information and carelessly tell people about schoolboy-Voldemort, it can indicate that Voldemort's identity was sort of common knowledge